# Cloud Run Flask API container running shutit enters a sleep loop

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

The issue has appeared recently and the previously healthy container now enters a sleep loop when a shutit session is being created. The issue occurs only on Cloud Run and not locally.

Minimum reproducible code:

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
shutit
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Cloud Run logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /myapp
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

CMD exec gunicorn \
 --bind :$PORT \
 --worker-class "sync" \
 --workers 1 \
 --threads 1 \
 --timeout 0 \
 main:app
```

`main.py`

```py
import os
import shutit
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# just to prove api works
@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    os.system('echo pong')
    return 'OK'

# issue replication
@app.route('/healthcheck', methods=['GET'])
def healthcheck():
    os.system("echo 'healthcheck'")
    # hangs inside create_session
    shell = shutit.create_session(echo=True, loglevel='debug')
    # never shell.send reached 
    shell.send('echo Hello World', echo=True)
    # never returned
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```yaml
steps:
  - id: "build_container"
    name: "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest"
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/borked-service-debug:latest
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=99h
  - id: "configure infrastructure"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        set -euxo pipefail

        REGION="europe-west1"
        CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE="borked-service-debug"

        SA_NAME="$${CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

        gcloud beta run deploy $${CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE} \
          --service-account "$${SA_NAME}" \
          --image gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/$${CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE}:latest \
          --allow-unauthenticated \
          --platform managed \
          --concurrency 1 \
          --max-instances 10 \
          --timeout 1000s \
          --cpu 1 \
          --memory=1Gi \
          --region "$${REGION}"
```

cloud run logs that get looped:

```
Setting up prompt
In session: host_child, trying to send: export PS1_ORIGIN_ENV=$PS1 && PS1='OR''IGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ' && PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .05||sleep 1'
================================================================================
Sending>>> export PS1_ORIGIN_ENV=$PS1 && PS1='OR''IGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ' && PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .05||sleep 1'<<<, expecting>>>['\r\nORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ']<<<
Sending in pexpect session (68242035994000): export PS1_ORIGIN_ENV=$PS1 && PS1='OR''IGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ' && PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .05||sleep 1'
Expecting: ['\r\nORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ']
export PS1_ORIGIN_ENV=$PS1 && PS1='OR''IGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ' && PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .05||sleep 1'
root@localhost:/myapp# export PS1_ORIGIN_ENV=$PS1 && PS1='OR''IGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# ' && PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .05||sleep 1'
Stopped sleep .05
Stopped sleep 1
pexpect: buffer: b'' before: b'cm9vdEBsb2NhbGhvc3Q6L3B1YnN1YiMgIGV4cx' after: b'DQpPUklHSU5fRU5WOnJra2ZRUTJ5IyA='
Resetting default expect to: ORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# 
In session: host_child, trying to send: stty cols 65535
================================================================================
Sending>>> stty cols 65535<<<, expecting>>>ORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# <<<
Sending in pexpect session (68242035994000): stty cols 65535
Expecting: ORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# 
ORIGIN_ENV:rkkfQQ2y# stty cols 65535
stty cols 65535
Stopped stty cols 65535
Stopped sleep .05
Stopped sleep 1
```

Workarounds tried:

- Different regions: a few European(tier 1 and 2), Asia, US.
- Build with docker instead of kaniko
- Different CPU and Memory allocated to the container
- [Minimum number of containers 1-5 (to ensure CPU is always allocated to the container)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation)
- `--no-cpu-throttling` also made no difference
- Maximum number of containers 1-30
- Different GCP project
- Different Docker base images (3.5-3.9 + various shas ranging from a year ago to recent ones)

Comment: Cloud Run does not support background tasks. When your Flask app returns the HTTP response, Cloud Run will idle the CPU. Your background tasks will then not have CPU time.

Comment: Is this a new restriction? Because this has been working perfectly fine until last Thursday.

Comment: No, this is not a new restriction and has been documented since the first release. You have just been lucky. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general

Comment: Not sure I follow. It's not really used as a background task, because the http response doesn't get returned until the shutit work is done. So CPU should still be allocated. And I can see in the Cloud Run dashboard that CPU is allocated to containers.

this hangs
 `shell = shutit.create_session(echo=True, loglevel='debug')`
this never executes `shell.send('echo Hello World', echo=True)`. never returns
`return 'OK'`
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation link I sent? Your application is packed in a container. The CPU is allocated to the thread that is running when you receive the HTTP Request. The execution model is HTTP Request/Response. **Shutit** is a wrapper for **Pexpect** which is a Python module for spawning child applications. Child applications run asynchronously to the Cloud Run thread.

Comment: Yes, and `when the Cloud Run service finishes handling a request, the container instance's access to CPU will be disabled or severely limited.` Hence if the request isn't finished the CPU is still there.

Additionally, in my original question, in the "workarounds tried" was minimum containers allocated 1-5. To ensure that CPU is always there to circumvent that possibility. According to this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation

Comment: updated the original question to clarify that CPU is always there.

Comment: Go to the logs. If the **shell.send()** never returns, then your Cloud Run thread should hang. Cloud Run will kill the container and you will see an error log entry. Instead of debating this issue, collect data that provides details on what is actually happening in your application.

Comment: It never gets to `shell.send()`. It hangs on `shell = shutit.create_session(echo=True, loglevel='debug')`. The container gets killed after too many `sleep` messages. The output from the logs is also in the original message. Instead of walking through debug again, let's read the message in full, and then write a reply. I've made sure it's a quality question, let's ensure they are quality answers

Comment: You have already answered your own question. If your app calls sleep too many times, Cloud Run kills the container. Don't call sleep. Cloud Run is not an asynchronous runtime system.

Comment: sleep is called by shutit...

Comment: Where you previously using Cloud Run with shutit to create sessions when you said the containers were healthy and worked fine?

Comment: That's right. And then all of a sudden it stopped working. Can't even link to any particular release in the notes

Comment: I can think of only this [latest release](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes#September_13_2021) in Cloud Run but you also mentioned you had tried --no-cpu-throttling for constant CPU allocation. Can you check if there were recent changes/updates on the shutit library you are using? Also have you upgraded to Python3 because python 2.7 is on its sunset and the [Gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/news.html#changelog) says the minimum version is python 3.5. Note : I am just suggesting a few possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, no worries at all, appreciate your reply! 

I've tried various versions of python3 (3.5 through to 3.9), latest gunicorn 1 and 2, no recent changes to shutit, the latest release, according to pypi was Jan 11, 2020.

Comment: Can you please try with "shutit.create_session('bash')"?

Comment: same effect and bash is also a default argument.

https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit/blob/master/shutit.py#L38

https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit/blob/master/shutit_global.py#L177

Comment: There is [known issue](https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit#known-issues), can you please try with setting a simple prompt?

Comment: how would you go about that? Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue and we have discussed several possibilities, I think the issue is your Cloud Run not being able to process requests and hence preparing to shut down(sigterm).
I am listing some possibilities for you to look at and analyse.

- A good reason for your Cloud Run service failing to start is that the
  server process inside the container is configured to listen on the
  localhost (127.0.0.1) address. This refers to the loopback network
  interface, which is not accessible from outside the container and
  therefore Cloud Run health check cannot be performed, causing the
  service deployment failure. To solve this, configure your application
  to start the HTTP server to listen on all network interfaces,
  commonly denoted as 0.0.0.0.
- While searching for the cloud logs error you are getting, I came
  across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26729953/15803365) and [GitHub link](https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit/blob/master/shutit_global.py#) from the shutit library
  developer which points to a technique for tracking inputs and outputs
  in complex container builds in shutit sessions.  One good finding
  from the GitHub link, I think you will have to pass the session_type
  in `shutit.create_session(‘bash’)` or `shutit.create_session(‘docker’)`
  which you are not specifying in the main.py file. That can be the
  reason your shutit session is failing.
- Also this issue could be due to some Linux kernel feature used by
  this shutit library which is not currently supported properly in
  [gVisor](https://gvisor.dev/) .  I am not sure how it was executed for you the first
  time. Most apps will work fine, or at least as well as in regular
  Docker, but may not provide 100% compatibility.

  Cloud Run applications run on gVisor container sandbox(which supports
  Linux only currently), which executes Linux kernel system calls made
  by your application in userspace. gVisor does not implement all
  system calls (see [here](https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/amd64/)). From this [Github link](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#which-system-calls-are-supported), “If your
  app has such a system call (quite rare), it will not work on Cloud
  Run. Such an event is [logged](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting?utm_campaign=CDR_ahm_aap-severless_cloud-run-faq_&utm_source=external&utm_medium=web#sandbox) and you can use [strace](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting/tracing-system-calls?utm_campaign=CDR_ahm_aap-severless_cloud-run-faq_&utm_source=external&utm_medium=web) to
  determine when the system call was made in your app”

  If you're running your code on Linux, install and enable strace:
  `sudo apt-get install strace` Run your application with strace by
  prefacing your usual invocation with strace -f where -f means to
  trace all child threads. For example, if you normally invoke your
  application with `./main`, you can run it with strace by invoking `/usr/bin/strace -f ./main`

  From this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#sandbox), “ if you feel your  issue is caused by
  a limitation in the Container sandbox . In the Cloud Logging section
  of the GCP Console (not in the "Logs'' tab of the Cloud Run section),
  you can look for `Container Sandbox` with a `DEBUG` severity in the
  `varlog/system` logs or use the Log Query:

> ```
> resource.type="cloud_run_revision"
> logName="projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem"
> ```

> For example: Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall
> setsockopt(0x3,0x1,0x6,0xc0000753d0,0x4,0x0)”

By default, container instances have min-instances turned off, with a setting of 0. We can change this default using the Cloud Console, the gcloud command line, or a YAML file, by specifying a minimum number of container instances to be kept warm and ready to serve requests.

You can also have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) and [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq) which talks about the Cloud Run container runtime behaviour and troubleshooting for reference.

Comment: Hi Priyashree, thank you soooo much for a really detailed response! 

I've gone through the tips you noted one by one: 

- 0.0.0.0 port. awesome suggestion, wish i tried that before, but unfortunately no dice. Still getting stuck.
- `create_session` with `bash` named argument unfortunately also brought no results. 
- strace was epic! I got `Unsupported syscall 
 process_vm_readv` during startup. Unfortunately it's hard for me to say if that's usual or normal. What do you think?

i did try the `--min-instances` during the initial troubleshooting, but that didn't affect the result

Comment: Okay now I would want you to try running your application locally on Docker using these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local) and verify if your applications boots fine locally?

Comment: Also the container must listen for requests on 0.0.0.0 on the port to which requests are sent. By default, requests are sent to 8080. Add the --min-instances in cloudbuild.yaml file and give it some value for now and then try.

Comment: @alanmynah any update?

Comment: Hi Priyashree, really sorry it took me awhile to get back to you. We've created a GKE cluster as a workaround for the problem and now I'm back.

I have followed the instructions for local VS Code setup. That was epic, didn't know of this, https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/developing-a-cloud-run-service

but unfortunately it worked. Or fortunately. Not sure. What are you thoughts? The container runs on 8080 and i can curl to both endpoints and i can see shutit output in `Cloud Run: Run/Debug` VSCode Output tab.

Comment: Great! So you are able to run it locally. That means there is no issue with the docker image or your configurations.`Unsupported syscall   process_vm_readv` - This message indicates that system calls may not be supported in this [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#sandbox)(fully managed) as container instances are sandboxed using the gVisor container runtime sandbox. Its a known issue in Cloud Run fully managed. You can try [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/setup) with same configurations and container setup(with less allocated resources)

Comment: We have chucked the workload into GKE now, so I guess, as a workaround that should be fine, but fully managed Cloud Run was still much much nicer. Oh well, thanks a lot for all your help. Still confused as to why it worked before and not any more.

Comment: Yes as per the steps we have followed in the debug process, I am confident that this is a Cloud Run sandbox issue. You can go ahead with GKE as well but to just let you know Cloud Run for Anthos is just a suitable alternative for Cloud Run fully managed specially for these cases. If you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Absolutely, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a chance you might now what gVisor versions we might try to reproduce the possible regression with?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect replacement but you can use one of the following instead:

I'm not sure what's the big picture so I'll add various options

For remote automation tasks from a flask web server we're using `paramiko` for its simplicity and quick setup, though you might prefer something like `pyinfra` for large projects or `subprocess` for small **local** tasks.

1. [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/) - a bit more hands-on\manual than `shutit`, run commands over the ssh protocol.

example:

```
import paramiko

ip='server ip'
port=22
# you can also use ssh keys
username='username'
password='password'

cmd='some useful command' 

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
outlines=stdout.readlines()
resp=''.join(outlines)
print(resp)
```

[more examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/4561/paramiko.SSHClient)

2. [pyinfra](https://pyinfra.com/) - ansible like library to automate tasks in ad-hoc style

example to install a package using apt:

```
from pyinfra.operations import apt

apt.packages(
    name='Ensure iftop is installed',
    packages=['iftop'],
    sudo=True,
    update=True,
)
```

3. [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/5459640) - like Paramiko not as extensive as `shutit` but works like a charm

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This was a bit of a simplified example with shutit, because the app is using it a bit more extensively and I just wanted to narrow down to the smallest possible repro example. But will probably give it a go to see if it'd be quick to rewrite using the suggestions you've provided. Thanks a lot

Comment: @alanmynah Glad it helped you, did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Afraid, not the underlying issue, but the workarounds are much appreciated too!

Comment: If you wouldn't find a resolving answer I'd appreciate accepting the answer